# I cant get my videos to show on my webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, video

I'm using php to load videos from my MYSQL database and display them on a web page. The videos are stored as urls to save database space. Whenever I load the web page I get the controls to play the video and nothing more. How do i get the video to show up?

```
<?php
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "videodata");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Starter Project</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML5 Audio</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      ?>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
<?php
}
}
?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you view the source of the page, what do you see as the "src" of the video?

Comment: Try `<?php echo $row['title']; ?>`.

Comment: Still nothing. Chris the src of the video should be <?php echo $row['title']; ?> but its not showing anything.

Comment: `var_dump` your `$row` please, does it even contain the data you need?

Comment: Yes it does give me the url to the video. If it helps here is what i get back: array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(66) "/Users/connor/Desktop/homeVideoStreamingStuff/XOPIntro.mp4" ["title"]=> string(66) "/Users/connor/Desktop/homeVideoStreamingStuff/XOPIntro.mp4" }

Comment: Then it should work fine with `<?php echo $row['title']; ?>`. Is it actually in your DOM and displaying the video does not work or is the `src` attribute really empty? In case of the first: `<source>` does not need a closing `</source>` tag. Try removing that.

Comment: Oh, and you should also try adding the `file://` protocol in front of the video path.

Comment: Alright I removed the closing source tag and still nothing showed up. I also added the file protocol and nothing happened there either.

Comment: I did not notice
Have you saved a movie link or saved the entire movie to your database?

Comment: Still nothing for me. I get the video player with controls. The var_dump is still showing me the location of the video but the video itself wont play. I can toggle the play/pause button on the player but the nothing happens.

Comment: I have the link uploaded to my database to save database space.

Comment: View Source on the page, and paste the whole ```<video``` link in your question.

Comment: The var_dump() result @ConnorWoodford provided shows that the "title" value is actually a local file path, instead of a URL. Firstly you need to make sure the mp4 file is accessible with an URL like `"http://localhost/..."` or something.

Answer (score 0):

- The `<source>` tag does not need a closing `</source>` tag.
- Make sure that a file contain in the path which returns from `$row['title']`.
- Also `$row[title]` should be changed into `$row['title']`.

  ```
  <?php 
  session_start(); 
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "videodata"); 
  ?> 
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html> 
   <head> 
     <title>Starter Project</title> 
     <meta charset="utf-8"> 
     <title>HTML5 Audio</title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
   <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM videos"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
   ?> 
       <video width="320" height="240" controls> 
        <source src="<?php echo $row['title'];?>" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
       </video> 
    <?php } } ?>
   </body> 
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have multiple types of videos, you can use the *src* attribute of the *video* tag:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls src="<?php echo $row[title]; ?>" type="video/mp4" />
```

Note that to play the video, it has to be in a format that the browser will play such as **webm** or **ogg**.